# Rearranging $sk^{0.5} - \delta k = 0$ to isolate $k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm going through an examination and the answer booklet and it gives the answer simply as
$$sk^{0.5} - \delta k = 0$$

rearrange to

$$k = (s/\delta)^2$$

Could anyone explain how to get to this answer?

Comment: Welcome to the site! It is very hard to give you an answer if you do not provide us with the full problem statement. Also, please check out the [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)!

Comment: hiya sorry i was just enquiring if anyone could tell me how to isolate k

Answer (score 2):

if your question is:$$s\times k^{0.5}-\delta\times k=0$$then fisrt add $\delta\times k$ to both sides to get:$$s\times k^{0.5}=\delta\times k$$then first divide both sides by $k^{0.5}$ to get:$$s=\delta\times k^{0.5}$$then divide both sides by $\delta$ to get:$$\frac{s}{\delta}=k^{0.5}$$and finally square both sides to get:$$(\frac{s}{\delta})^2=k$$

Comment: thanks alot youve helped me alot here

Comment: you're welcome :)